# Is there a better way to join multiple column values from table to another?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this (table2):

```
   JoinID ID Value
   1234     1  101
   1234     2  102
   1234     3  103
   1234     4  104
```

I want to join it to another table (table1) so I have one row with specific ID's as columns such as:

```
JoinID ID_1 ID_2 ID_3 OtherStuffFromOthertables
1234   101  102  103  123456789
```

I'm currently doing this by doing multiple joins like this:

```
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.JoinID = t1.JoinID and ID = 1
LEFT JOIN table2 t3 ON t3.JoinID = t1.JoinID and ID = 2
LEFT JOIN table2 t4 ON t4.JoinID = t1.JoinID and ID = 3
```

This is working but I feel like there is a better way to do than doing a bunch of joins. Is there something I'm missing that will make this cleaner and a bit faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is fine.  An alternative is conditional aggregation:

```
select t1.JoinId,
       max(case when t2.id = 1 then t2.value end) as value_1,
       max(case when t2.id = 2 then t2.value end) as value_2,
       max(case when t2.id = 3 then t2.value end) as value_3
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t2.JoinID = t1.JoinId
group by t1.JoinId;
```

As the number of columns grows, this will come to have better performance (typically).  However, if performance is an issue, you might want to see which is better.

Actually, in SQL Server, the best performance is probably a hybrid using `outer apply`:

```
select t1.JoinId, t2.*
from table1 t1 outer apply
     (select max(case when t2.id = 1 then t2.value end) as value_1,
             max(case when t2.id = 2 then t2.value end) as value_2,
             max(case when t2.id = 3 then t2.value end) as value_3
      from table2 t2
      where t2.JoinID = t1.JoinId
     ) t2;
```

This avoids the aggregation on the full data -- opting for smaller aggregations per row.  It also only references `table2` once and can take maximal advantage of an index on `table2(JoinId, id, value)`.